# Proposed tag synonym or name change [cake tag]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think that the cake tag should probably be a synonym for cakephp. It usually seems to be what the tag refers to.

If cake is mainly used for cakephp versions < 1.2 (I'm not sure) it should maybe be renamed to make it more obvious that the tag is for older versions of cakephp.

Comment: What about SOs (Significant Others, not the other SO!) wanting to do an awesome birthday cake?

Comment: Then it should be tagged [tag:birthday-cake] :).